# Add text upper left corner Wordpress Storefront

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

This started out as a Question, but I sort of made it work. I am sharing it for anyone who needs to know. Or maybe there is a better way?

I'd like to show a welcome message on the home page. Should be placed in the upper left corner.

This is what I did:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'pfn_userinheader',1);
function pfn_userinheader() {
        ?>
    <span class="pfn_great_header2"><a href="\cart"> Hello! blablabla</a></span>
        <?php
        }
```

Now the text is placed where the secondary menu. More like top, right of middle. I have no idea why just there. Anyway, I would like it to be placed in the top left corner.

This is my css:

```
 .pfn_great_header2{
        position: absolute !important;
        left: 0;
        top:0;
        width: 10% !important;
        color: #0071A1;
    }
```

It works. Is it a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar on my site but it displays a different message if the customer is already logged in.

If you wanted to do this, you could use something like this:

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'pfn_userinheader',1);

function pfn_userinheader() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<span class="pfn_great_header2">Welcome back <?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo $current_user->user_firstname; ?>!</span>';
    }
    elseif {
    echo '<span class="pfn_great_header2"><a href="\cart"> Hello! blablabla</a></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. My code is actually similar to yours. But since my question was about placement I removed that part.